# Issues with HTML canvas and object oriented JavaScript character for HTML game

Tags: javascript, html, oop, canvas

The issue is, the HTML canvas is not outputting a character object inside the canvas. The canvas is defined as the `gameArea` and the character is defined as a character. Both have been written in JavaScript, and the character is made into an object.

This is for a 2D platformer game, so far I have tried to change the character form an object to a variable to see whether the encapsulation of the object was causing issues, but this has not worked. I have also tried to add a new function within the character object called update, in order to make sure the character (rectangle) is filled when moving.

Here is my code:

The first section **declares the character variable, and also has a function**, which is started first in the HTML using `onload`:

```
var Character;

function startGame(){
    gameArea.start();
    Character = new character(40, 80, "#4286f4", 30, 500, true, 0, 0);
}
```

The parameters for the character object are `width`, `height`, `colour`, x, y, jumping state, `speedX` and `speedY` (also shown later on in the code).

The second section shows the **gameArea variable (the canvas)**, I have also called my EventListeners of Keydown and Keyup here:

```
var gameArea = {
    canvas: document.getElementById("canvas"), //Defining the canvas' 
    //dimensions
    start: function() {
        this.canvas.width = 700;
        this.canvas.height = 500;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas,document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {//EventListener 
    functions
            gameArea.keys = (gameArea.keys || []);
            gameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            gameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
    },
    clear : function(){
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}
```

The next section is the **character object**:

```
function character(width, height, color, x, y, jumping, speedX, speedY) 
{//Character object, blue rectangle
    this.jumping=jumping;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speedX = speedX;
    this.speedY= speedY;
    ctx = gameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.width, this.height, this.x, this.y);
    this.update = function() {//Updating the gameArea function
        ctx = gameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
 }
```

**To my knowledge, the code above is the only relevant code to the issue.** If needed the rest of the code (the controller logic and movement mechanics) can be found below:

```
   function updateGameArea() {
    gameArea.clear();
    character.speedX = 0;
    character.speedY = 0;
    character.update();
    var controller = {

        up: false,
        down: false,
        left: false,
        right: false,
        keyListener: function (event) {
            var keyPosition = (event.type == "keydown") ? true : false;
            switch (event.keyCode) {
                case 87:
                    controller.up = keyPosition;
                    break;

                case 83:
                    controller.down = keyPosition;
                    break;

                case 65:
                    controller.left = keyPosition;
                    break;

                case 68:
                    controller.right = keyPosition;
                    break;

            }
        }
    };

        if (controller.up && character.jumping == false) {
            character.speedY -= 2.5
            character.jumping = true;
        }
        if (controller.down) {
            character.speedY += 2.5;
        }
        if (controller.left) {
            character.speedX -= 2.5;
        }
        if (controller.right) {
            character.speedX += 2.5;
        }

        character.speedY += 1.5;
        character.x = character.speedX;
        character.y = character.speedY;
        character.speedX *= 0.9;
        character.speedY *= 0.9

        var ground = gameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > ground) {
            character.jumping = false;
            character.y = ground;
            character.speedY = 0;
        }

    }
```

Expected results: character displays inside the canvas and has the correct movement

Actual results: character does not display.

I understand that there is a lot of code here, but I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the correct direction, as I don't really understand why the character does not display in the canvas.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the character's position to 500 so he is drawn outside of the visible area (the canvas is only 500 tall). 
x= 0, y= 0 is in the top right in a canvas.

Change `Character = new character(40, 80, "#4286f4", 30, 500, true, 0, 0);`

To `Character = new character(40, 80, "#4286f4", 30, 400, true, 0, 0);`

**EDIT:** Rewrote the whole thing.

```js
var character, ctx;

function startGame() {

  gameArea.start();
  character = new Character(40, 80, "#4286f4", 30, 400, true, 0, 0);
  gameArea.clear();
  updateGameArea();
}

let gameArea = {
  start() {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); //Defining the canvas' 
    this.canvas.width = 700;
    this.canvas.height = 500;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    
  },
  clear() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  },
}

function Character(width, height, color, x, y, jumping, speedX, speedY) { //Character object, blue rectangle
  this.jumping = jumping;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.position = {
    x,
    y
  };
  this.velocity = {
    x: speedX,
    y: speedY
  };
  ctx = gameArea.context;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(this.width, this.height, this.x, this.y);
  this.color = color;
 return this;
}
Character.prototype = {
  update() { //Updating the gameArea function
   
    character.position.x += character.velocity.x;
    character.position.y += character.velocity.y;
    
    let ground = gameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
    if (this.position.y > ground) {
      character.jumping = false;
      character.position.y = ground;
      character.velocity.y = 0;
    }
    
    ctx = gameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.width, this.height);
  }
}
var controller = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 87:
      controller.y = -1;
      break;

    case 83:
      controller.y = 1;
      break;

    case 65:
      controller.x = -1;
      break;

    case 68:
      controller.x = 1;
      break;
  }

});
document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 87:
      controller.y = 0;
      break;

    case 83:
      controller.y = 0;
      break;

    case 65:
      controller.x = 0;
      break;

    case 68:
      controller.x = 0;
      break;
  }

});

function updateGameArea() {
  
  gameArea.clear();
  character.velocity.x = controller.x;
  character.velocity.y = controller.y;
  character.update();
  requestAnimationFrame(updateGameArea);
}

window.onload = startGame;
```

```css
canvas {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I also made some minor changes to the gameArea I included the snippet so you can check them.

Comment: The character does not move, do you know what could be causing this? Also, thanks for your solution to the visibility issue

Comment: You are SETTING the character x and y to the speed instead of ADDING which is what I think you meant to do.

Comment: Also you are changing variables of character and Character. And you never set controller.keyListener as an event listener.

Comment: Ok, how would I add the speed, rather than setting it, and i'll set the controller.keyListener

Comment: I rewrote the code you gave. Hopefully you should be able to figure out where you went wrong from there. If not, lmk. I think you are confused on the coordinate system in canvas so look that up.